# Get id from json file without Generate an automatical value

Tags: java, json, spring

I have a json file to parse which contain ID value, example:

```
{
  "test": [
           {
            "id": "14",
             ...
          }
       ]
}
```

In java class (I'm using Spring MVC) I have this :

```
    @Id
    private Integer id;
```

When I import my json into a database, it changes the id value. I need to get the same **id** which is in Json file (in this case 14) but in DB generate another value (I didn't use `@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)` in my java class).

My controller:

in Java I read the id like this:

```
@Autowired
    TestService testService;


String id = (String)qobj.get("id");
int idq = Integer.parseInt(id);
test.setId(idq);
testService.save(test);
```

Service:

```
  @Override
    public Test save(Test q) {
        return repository.save(q);
    }
```

Could someone tell me why this changes the id value? Even if I did not specify `GeneratedValue` annotation? And if you have any idea to solve it?

Comment: You need to provide more.For example any controllers if you are using spring mvc or spirng rest or any services where you try to save data into the database.

Comment: I edit my question and I add some information

Answer (score 0):

I've found my error, it works now.